# unable to setup react using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

I have started working on react and to practice I have installed `Node 12` which installed `npm` automatically than I created a folder "`reacthello`" and than typed `"npm -i"` than `"npm i -g create-react-app"` but its throwing the following error again and again even I tried with `npx` also. By the way I have cleared the cache by force as well `"npm cache clean --force"` but this error is not going away. Anyone can help me here I would be grateful and guide me the right direction.

```
E:\reactjsapps>npx create-react-app myapp-01
[############......] | finalize:jsonfile: sill finalize C:\Users\user.id\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\10908\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\jsonfile[############......] | finalize:jsonfile: sill finalize C:\Users\user.id\Apnpm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user.id\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\10908\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\lodash
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\user.id\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\10908\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\.lodash.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\user.id\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\10908\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\lodash' -> 'C:\Users\user.id\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\10908\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\.lodash.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user.id\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-15T07_48_30_687Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 4294963238
D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:313
        throw er
        ^

Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\user.id\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\10908'
[90m    at Object.rmdirSync (fs.js:752:3)[39m
    at rmkidsSync (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\[4mnpm[24m\node_modules\[4mrimraf[24m\rimraf.js:356:25)
    at rmdirSync (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\[4mnpm[24m\node_modules\[4mrimraf[24m\rimraf.js:334:7)
    at Function.rimrafSync [as sync] (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\[4mnpm[24m\node_modules\[4mrimraf[24m\rimraf.js:304:9)
    at process.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\[4mnpm[24m\node_modules\[4mlibnpx[24m\index.js:151:37)
[90m    at process.emit (events.js:223:5)[39m {
  errno: [33m-4051[39m,
  syscall: [32m'rmdir'[39m,
  code: [32m'ENOTEMPTY'[39m,
  path: [32m'C:\\Users\\user.id\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\10908'[39m
}
```

Comment: try deleting this file `C:\\Users\\user.id\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\10908`

Comment: I did and it created it globally but when I executed "npx create-react-app myapp-01" it aborted at the end. whats the right way to create project?

Answer (score 0):

dont name your project in command (npx create-react-app myapp-01).

create your folder and inside that  run (npx create-react-app . )

use ( dot )